# Crystal Reports - Adding a parameter to a 'Command' query

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Version - Crystal Reports 2008
Business Objects - XI

I have written a query to populate a subreport and want to pull in a parameter to that query based on input from a user.  My question is, what is the correct syntax I need to put in the first line of the 'Where' clause to accept the parameter?

Here is the query I am using in Crystal Reports:

```
Select 
Projecttname,
ReleaseDate,
TaskName

From DB_Table

Where
(Project_Name like {?Pm-?Proj_Name})) and 
(ReleaseDate) >= currentdate
```

Comment: I have tried declaring and setting a variable at the top of the SQL and I still do not see the parameter I select in the SQL, when I look at the subreport's SQL.  Am I doing something wrong?                                                           declare @ProjName varchar(200)
set @ProjName = '{?Pm-?Proj_Name}'                               Select 
Projecttname,
ReleaseDate,
TaskName

From DB_Table

Where
(Project_Name) like @ProjName and 
(ReleaseDate) >= currentdate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I came up with was as follows:

1. Create the SQL query in your favorite query dev tool
2. In Crystal Reports, within the main report, create parameter to pass to the subreport
3. Create sub report, using the 'Add Command' option in the 'Data' portion of the 'Report Creation Wizard' and the SQL query from #1.
4. Once the subreport is added to the main report, right click on the subreport, choose 'Change Subreport Links...', select the link field, and uncheck 'Select data in subreport based on field:'

   NOTE: You may have to initially add the parameter with the 'Select data in subreport based on field:' checked, then go back to 'Change Subreport Links ' and uncheck it after the subreport has been created.
5. In the subreport, click the 'Report' menu, 'Select Expert', use the 'Formula Editor', set the SQL column from #1 either equal to or like the parameter(s) selected in #4.

   ```
                   (Subreport SQL Column)  (Parameter from Main Report)
           Example:  {Command.Project} like {?Pm-?Proj_Name}
   ```

Comment: Filtering on the Crystal level is very inefficient. It is better to filter at the database level when possible.

Answer (score 15):

When you are in the Command, click Create to create a new parameter; call it `project_name`.  Once you've created it, double click its name to add it to the command's text.  You query should resemble:

```
SELECT Projecttname, ReleaseDate, TaskName
FROM DB_Table
WHERE Project_Name LIKE {?project_name} + '*'
AND ReleaseDate >= getdate() --assumes sql server
```

If desired, link the main report to the subreport on this (`{?project_name}`) field.  If you don't establish a link between the main and subreport, CR will prompt you for the subreport's parameter.

In versions prior to 2008, a command's parameter was only allowed to be a scalar value.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Projecttname, ReleaseDate, TaskName From DB_Table Where Project_Name like '%{?Pm-?Proj_Name}%' and ReleaseDate >= currentdate
```

Note the single-quotes and wildcard characters. I just spent 30 minutes figuring out something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Project_Name, ReleaseDate, TaskName
From DB_Table
Where Project_Name like '{?Pm-?Proj_Name}'
  And ReleaseDate >= currentdate
```

*currentdate* should be a valid database function or field to work. If you are using MS SQL Server, use GETDATE() instead.

If all you want is to filter records in a subreport based on a parameter from the main report, it might be easier to simply add the table to the subreport, and then create a Project_Name link between the main report and subreport. You can then use the Select Expert to filter the ReleaseDate as well.

Comment: Would this work?  Where Project_Name like ?'{?Pm-?Proj_Name}'
When I run the query and go to 'Database', 'Show SQL', I still see the text'{?Pm-?Proj_Name}' and not the parameter that I entered.  Is that correct?

Comment: So I have tried declaring and setting a variable at the top of the SQL.

Comment: _Show SQL_ will still show the parameter name. I'm assuming you want to use wildcards in your where clause? You can use these SQL wildcards:
%: match all characters.
_: match a single character.
Examples:
`where Project_Name like '%{?Pm-?Proj_Name}%'` to load records with Project_Name containing {?Pm-?Proj_Name}.
`where Project_Name like '_{?Pm-?Proj_Name}'` to load records with Project_Name with a single letter before {?Pm-?Proj_Name}.

Comment: Declaring and setting a variable will not make a difference afaik. Do you get an error message when you use the query in my answer? If so, what is it?

Comment: No, I did not get an error.  However, when I show the query of the sub report, I do not see the parameter I entered.  I only see: Where Project_Name like '{?Pm-?Proj_Name}'

Comment: That is as expected. You will not see the parameter value at design-time. Place the parameter on the header section of the subreport and run the report to see the values being passed.