# crystal reports table source difficulty with user defined functions

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports, user-defined-functions

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Muffins
WHERE OvenLoadId IN (
    SELECT OvenLoadId 
    FROM tbl_Muffins
    WHERE OrderId = ?
    GROUP BY OvenLoadId
)
ORDER BY OvenLoadId, LocationNumber ASC
```

The idea of the query is that I want to specify an OrderId, and I want all Oven Loads that have items from that order in them, as well as ALL OTHER ITEMS in those loads, even though they could be from other orders.

The query works as expected, but I'm not able to use it for my Crystal Report I've written it for.

I have put this query into a User Defined Function, however I'm unable to use a call to that function as a table source in my Crystal Report.  I am using Visual Studio 2003 (I know it is old, the client refuses to upgrade).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

jnsohnumr

Comment: Can't you turn this into a view or stored procedure and use that as your source in Crystal Reports?

Comment: not sure how to do that.  can't be a view, as it needs to take a parameter.  how does one use a stored procedure as a table source for crystal reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 9 of Crystal Reports onwards, it became possible to report from custom queries using Crystal's ["Add Command"](http://www.ehow.com/how_6540670_write-report-oracle-using-sql.html) functionality.

There is a description of adding a parameter to a command query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018321/crystal-reports-adding-a-parameter-to-a-command-query).

Comment: I will give that a try.  Is the version that ships with Visual Studio 2003 version 9?  According to this page it is:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225607(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I don't know - I don't have VS 2003. The easiest way to find out would be to open the Crystal Reports designer and select Help > About Crystal Reports... from the menues.

Comment: well that kind of works.  got a query without a parameter to work.  got one with a parameter to work sometimes.  i keep getting access violations when i save the command and try to run the verify DB.  luckily client cancelled this report so i'm moving on to something else.  seems like crystal reports is pretty flakey.