# Crystal Reports & Access 2013 - Continuous Form?

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports

## Original Question

---

In Crystal Reports 2011, how do I show all values from a certain Field?

My formula that pulls the data from an Access DB is simply:

```
{tblQuoteFormSub_Windows.fQty} & " - " & 
{tblQuoteFormSub_Windows.fWindowSizeW} & 
 " x " & {tblQuoteFormSub_Windows.fWindowSizeH}
```

If I right click on the field in Design or Preview Mode, I can select "Browse Field Data, and see all the values, but I cannot figure out how to print all of them.

### EDIT:

---

I used a sub report (I am still learning, and didn't know they existed in CR until today). Now I can view the records I need based on the fJobID Field.

#### However...

I need a way to select which group to print... Preferably by using a control in Access to select a Job #. Should I post that as a new question?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you're almost there. Simply drag that formula into the Details section of your Crystal report. Then I think it will display and print the way you expect. Does that help?

Comment: No, when I drag the formula onto the report, it only prints one value, not all three.

Comment: Did you drag it into the Details section? If you put it in the report header, page header, or group header sections, it will only print the first value.

Comment: Yes I did, I put it in it's own detail section, specifically "Details h". I THINK i may have a thought about it... I have not set up any sorting or grouping values yet, and I am unsure exactly how to do so, could that be a cause?

Comment: I don't think that's it, but I see now I didn't understand your question as well as I originally thought. CR thinks in terms of records. It can print each record one by one with summaries.  Are you trying to display every possible value of this field for every single record? Can you edit your post and give us some more details?

Comment: I've updated my original question now, thanks for the advice thus far... DON'T LEAVE ME!!! :)

Comment: (Also, lol to the "DON'T LEAVE ME" comment)

Answer (score 0):

The subreport is a good idea.  I was thinking of suggesting that, but I wasn't sure if it would have met your needs.  I haven't tried Access 2013 yet, and it's been awhile since I've even seen CR.  But as for your other question, I can give you one suggestion that I used with previous versions.

In your Access query, add a parameter to your query, i.e. `Select * from mytable where job='[Enter Job Num]'`. Then when you preview your CR, that parameter should filter through so that it will ask you for the job number when you preview it.

Give it a try and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Okay, I will try that, and it sounds very reasonable. But where should I add that query? The report in CR is 100% made in CR, but it references about 28 tables.

Comment: Oh, this won't work then.  I was assuming that your query was built entirely in Access and only the result table was pulled into CR. I'm sure you can create a parameter field in CR that works the same way, but that's beyond my ability by now.  You'll have to google for it.  Try <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018321/crystal-reports-adding-a-parameter-to-a-command-query>

Comment: Okay... I will look into that, but here is a question. Every table in my Database is linked to one main "index" table. It has a field called fJobID that links every other table to that specific job. There is a ComboBox on my form that is used as a lookup for that fJobID. Can I use that main table in a Query somehow that you may know about?

Comment: Yes, I think so. That's why I'm suggesting you look up how to use parameters in CR.  Then you can use that jobid field as a parameter.

Comment: Okay, I will continue to look into that. And If I need more assistance, I will post a new question. Thanks for the help.