# How do I pass the same parameter to multiple Command statements in Crystal Reports XI?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, sql-server-express, crystal-reports-xi

My DB does not have the tables I need, so I have to create custom SQL queries (commands in Crystal terminology), embed the results in a subreport, and fill my report with subreports. Here's what I want to happen:

1. Report asks user for a date
2. That date gets passed into the subreports
3. The date passed into subreports gets used in the query.
4. User only has to enter date once, everything else happens behind the scenes

Here's what actually happens:

1. User is asked for date for subreport 1
2. User is asked for date for subreport 2
3. etc etc
4. User gets frustrated and report is unsuccessful.

I know I can link parameter fields between reports, but as I understand it, I cannot do the same with commands. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Check out this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018321/crystal-reports-adding-a-parameter-to-a-command-query

Comment: @NepaliRookie I figured it out! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Right-click on the subreport object and choose Change SubReport Links,
>   then select how the parameter is to be used by the subreport.

Courtesy: @MartW

Comment: The parameter is in the command itself, so it doesn't appear as an option in the Change Subreport Links window. Here's one of the commands:

  `SELECT COUNT("PRIORITY") AS TotalWO`
  `FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"`
  `WHERE DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})`
 `AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})`

The `reportingDate` parameter has the same name in all queries but it still asks for them with every query.

Comment: @ijustlovemath Have you tried creating a variable that you can pass on both main report and subreports?

Comment: Check out this link here on how to use a shared variable in CR http://www.ehow.com/how_5287432_use-shared-variable-crystal-report.html

Comment: Ah yea, I've tried that too. It doesn't work as I think the SQL query is a bit lower level than that.

Comment: Please do me a favor and upvote my answer if you feel this helped. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote, or I would! Sorry

Comment: You should be able to now.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong about the links not working. They do work, with modification.

As long as your queries are using parameters named the same way, this can work. With the default linking, you'll get a parameter window that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuCxA.jpg. If you modify your linking to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N4Wi.jpg, then the reportingDate parameter used in the main report will be passed into the individual SQL queries of the subreports, as expected. Thanks to Nepali for pushing me in the right direction!